# Dynamically Merge Text Columns Into One Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database that looks like this:

```
ID  A    B      C      D....
1       HKU
2              3MC  
3  Main 
4  Main               FT
```

The dataframe is updated every week and when there isn't a record in a column then that column does not appear in the dataframe. There are typically over 20 columns. So for example, say this is week 1, there is a record in the 'B' column, but if there is not a record in column B next week, then B column would not be included in the dataframe (I have no control over the back-end design of the dataframe).

I have a code that will concatenate columns, but when a column name is not in the code, I get an error that says variable is not in the dataframe.

```
 new_ADM1['concat'] = pd.Series(new_ADM1[['A, 'B','C'...]].fillna('').values.tolist()).str.join(' ')
```

I need to dynamically create a concatenation column of all columns that are not the ID column, regardless of how many columns there are in my dataframe.

I would like the new dataframe to look this like this with a concatenation column that combines all of the text in the A to ... columns by ID.

```
ID  A    B      C      D....    concat
1       HKU                       HKU
2              3MC                3MC
3  Main                           Main
4  Main               FT          Main, FT
```

Comment: `df['concat'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)`?

Comment: pd.Series(new_ADM1.drop('ID',1).fillna('').values.tolist()).str.join(' ')